# Sudo during Ninja Build

Tags: cmake, ninja

I have a project build using cmake + make that uses a macro to change capabilites on the app files.

I'm trying to switch from make to ninja, but when sudo needs to ask me the root password in order to run setcap ninja doesn't show the request and doesn't allow me to insert it.

Is it possible to do something about it ?

PS. Moving the setcap execution out of the build time is not an option because the other guys are using make and they are happy this way !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target that executes sudo should be in the console pool

> There exists a pre-defined pool named console with a depth of 1. It
>   has the special property that **any task in the pool has direct access**
>   **to the standard input**, output and error streams provided to Ninja,
>   which are normally connected to the user’s console (hence the name)
>   but could be redirected. This can be useful for interactive tasks or
>   long-running tasks which produce status updates on the console (such
>   as test suites).

[Docs](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html#_the_literal_console_literal_pool)

Comment: Thank you very much, it was what i was looking for, but when I added to my add_custom_command USES_TERMINAL (cmake version 3.7.2), sadly nothing changed.

Comment: Did you check if that really translates as needed in the generated Ninja.build file?

Comment: You are right. I manually added pool=console inside the  link build of the ninja file and it worked. So it seems a problem with the CMake generator.